# What is the difference between arango search and filter keyword

Tags: arangodb

Can somebody explain in details on difference between :

```
Search and filter keyword
```

I have already gone through https://www.arangodb.com/learn/search/tutorial/  -> **SEARCH vs FILTER**

Do anybody has any other experience on the difference?

Thanks,
Nilotpal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FILTER` corresponds to the `WHERE` clause in SQL. It does, what the name says. It uses all sorts of arithmetic and AQL operators to filter the search result. It can make use of regular indexes. There is no ranking of filtered results. Filters operate on single collection result sets.

`SEARCH` offers a full fledged search engine very much like what you would get from regular search engines like Google's page ranking based on a grammar that you could formulate on your own and can operate on multiple collection contents. Its most natural functionality would be a full text search and ranking. In that use it would be a much more powerful version of the full-text index. But it can do much more: normalisation, tokenisation based on language ...

The list goes on and on. Please refer to the documentation of search here:

https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/arangosearch.html